# C++ class and freeglut (argument type does not match)

Tags: c++, class, types, match, freeglut

I want to create a class to keep my variables that a lot of functions will use like mouse position and other things. Here's what I made:

test.h:

```
class test{
public:
    test();
    virtual ~test();

    void update(int n);

    //Desenhar
    void draw(void);

private:
    int mx, my; //Mouse variables
};
```

test.cpp:

```
test::test(){
}

test::test(){
}

void test::update(int n){
    glutTimerFunc(20, this->update, 0);
}

void test::draw(void){
    ...
    circle(mx, my);
    ...
}
```

The problem I have is that I can't use the update method with `glutTimerFunc()` (like `glutTimerFunc(20, this->update, 0);`) because it's not a `static` function. Even if I'm using object.update (on the `main` function where I created a instance for the class called `object`), it says that the argument type does not match (`error: argument of type 'void (test::)(int)' does not match 'void (*)(int)'`)

If I change it to static (as a lot of questions here says that I should), I can't use mx or my on the draw method because it doesn't have an instance.

Is there any solution? I'm making this way because I need some variables in a lot of methods and the best way would be creating an instance of this class on the main function and all the methods inside this class. Am I doing something that I shouldn't do?

Sorry if the solution is easy, I'm new to C++ and never used a class this way, it's the first time.

Comment: What does making `update()` `static` have to do with the `draw()` method? Can you explain why it wouldn't have an instance?

Comment: sorry if it wasn't clear. both functions are used just like the example I used with update. The problem is if I use any variable of the class inside update/draw, these methods can't be static. If I make the methods static, I can't use any variables of the object.

Comment: He said "make it static or use an ordinary global function". As I said, static doesn't help.
I'm using a class just to avoid global variables, If I use another function, then I didn't have to create a class

Comment: I think you're going to have to make `mx` and `my` global then. I don't see any other way right now.

Comment: but there will be a lot more variables. I learned that creating global variables was a bad practice

Answer (score 0):

The solution I am currently using involves a global wrapper around the instance methods.

You need a class with static methods or just regular functions which call the instance methods on memorized instance reference. In case of static class methods you usually provide some sort of "init" method which accepts a reference to your instance. You set up GLUT callbacks to static methods which in turn call methods on stored reference.

In case of regular functions, you expose an "init" function which takes a reference to your instance and stores it in global variable (usually you want it to be global just for the file where your functions are). And as in the case above, you set GLUT callbacks to your regular functions in the file which then call appropriate methods on your globally stored reference.
Of course, you only want to expose "init" function to other code and keep the global variable and callback functions hidden.

Hope you understood. Tell me if you want code example.